# Install remaining drivers after installation

Tags: drivers, sound

Earlier, I installed my Ubuntu 16.04 Server via the console and went through a large TUI process in which I configured several options regarding the new installation. One option I chose was not to install any additional drivers, but just those that were needed for my hardware configuration. I believed, since changing the internal hardware was not planned on this server, that this would be fine.

Now, I notice that my USB sound card which works fine on my normal Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop installation does not work from this server installation. Inserting it properly creates the `/proc/asound/card1` directory and the files there seem to make sense, but when I type `asound -l` I get the error message `no soundcards found...` and attempting to play any files gives a similar error message. I believe this is caused by a missing driver, but I am not even sure about this and do not know which one this could be.

Is there a way to still install the remaining drivers that I skipped during my initial installation?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the prolem was. It was not related to the drivers, but rather to the fact that my user was not a member of the `audio` group. Running `sudo usermod -aG audio [username]` solved my problem after logging out and back in.